# jquery $.post not working in the load callback function?

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

here is mycode

```
$('#edit-popout-warpper').load(url,function(){
  //the url contain the editnameform
            $('#editnameform').submit(function(e){
                e.preventDefault(); 
                var $form = $( this ),
                    term = $form.find( 'input[name="mymoname"]' ).val(),
                    urll = $form.attr( 'action' );
                $.post(urll,{mymoname:term});

            })
        })
        return false;
```

after i use jquery ajax load method the $.post is not working ,its not sending the post request any idea why?

i finally get it work only i used $.ajax like this

```
 $.ajax({
         type:'POST',
         url:urll,
         data:{mymoname:term}
       })
```

i don't know why. but at lest it worked.so anyone knows why the $,post not working please let me know thanx

Comment: Is this `#editnameform` found? You can try `alert($('#editnameform').length);` on the first row of the callback function

Comment: Can you reproduce it in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Can you check Developer Toolbar (normally F12) Network tab. What is error code you get from the request? Headers would be also handy.

Comment: i use firebug after i click the submit button nothing happen not even a error message

Answer (score 0):

You missed the post callback function.

```
$('#editnameform').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $form = $(this),
        term = $form.find('input[name="mymoname"]').val(),
        urll = $form.attr('action');
    $.post(urll, {
        mymoname: term
    }, function(data) {
       console.log(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: @chenliang So the problem is you missed the callback function.

Comment: isn't the $.post callback optional?

Comment: @chenliang How did you know your `$.post` is not working? Have you check the http request and response??

Comment: i use the firebug and the console dosen't show a post request; and my database is not updated,when i use the normal way to submit the form it worked and there is a post request